# Easy way to set index.html <title>title</title> to child iframe title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, title

Is there an easy way to set the `<title>*</title>` of my index.html by looking at the `<title>*</title>` of a child iframe?

[My site as example](https://deepmotions.github.io/)

When the content in the iframe changes, will the title change with it then?

Comment: Your iframe does not have title

Comment: I know, but what if I can give it a title.

Comment: Dynamically setting the title will defeat its purpose (which is SEO).
Nevertheless, here is a way to dynamically set a title: `document.title = "new title."`

Comment: I'm not good at javascript at all, so where should I put this and what should I insert into my document.

Answer (score 0):

**For Only Web Pages are on same Domain.**

```
var title = $("#IframeID").contents().find("title").html();
 $(document).attr('title',title);
```

Comment: I'm not that good at javascript or jquery, so what do I need to add to my documents and where should I add it? I tried this before but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to download jQuery 3.2.1 from https://jquery.com/download/ add this in your project then reference JQuery file in the header of your file

Comment: And where do I put the script you just gave me?

Comment: so you put this script at the bottom of your page (after closing bracket of your body tag i.e </body>) just like this :
<script type="text/javascript"> var title = $("#IframeID").contents().find("title").html();
$(document).find("title").html(title); </script>

Comment: My site is updated now, but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your Iframe title is Home and see at your page title is changed to Home

Comment: It doesn't seem like it changed the <title></title> of the index.html, which is where I'm going for.

Comment: ok replace previous script with this one:  
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function () {
var title = $("#IframeID").contents().find("title").html();
 $(document).attr('title',title);
});
</script>

Comment: Oops sorry try this :
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var title = $("#IframeID").contents().find("title").html(); $(document).attr('title',title);  
</script>

Comment: Also doesn't seem to work. I guess it is just not possible in my case.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">document.title = document.getElementById('page').contentWindow.document.title;</script>

Seems to work, but it won't set a title.